# PHP MYSQL: Delete user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that, when submitted, will delete a users profile by processing `deleteuser.php`.

```html
<form method='post' action='deleteuser.php'>
    <input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete Profile'>
```

And here is the deleteuser.php

```php
session_start();
include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $id = $_SESSION['uid'];    

    $sql = "DELETE from users WHERE id='$id'";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "User has been sucessfully deleted!";
}
else{
    echo "ERROR: User was not deleted";
}
```

Now I am only getting "User was not deleted".

Any idea why?

Comment: You are checking for `$_POST['submit']`, but there is no element with `name="submit"`. You may want `$_POST['delete']`.

Comment: Also, please look into `mysqli_`

Comment: Depending on how `$_SESSION['uid']` is set you might be open to an injection with this code.

Comment: Is there any tool I can download that can convert my files to mysqli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @showdev, `form` post data associated with their name tag, i.e. since

```
<input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete Profile'>
```

as `name` tag set to "delete", you must access it via `$_POST['delete']`